# access anbox-cloud using public IP Address

Tags: internet

I have installed anbox-cloud on a bare metal server which is behind a firewall.

The same server is exposed to internet using a public IP address.

While trying to create anbox session from dashboard (using public address over internet) , session is not created .

On observing the network requests from developer tools , it is observed that wss:// url is still using the local server IP instead of public IP address.

I tried to change the location config of anbox-stream-agent , anbox-stream-gateway and coturn to public IP address.

/snap/bin/juju config -m appliance:admin/anbox-cloud coturn location=publicipaddress
/snap/bin/juju config -m appliance:admin/anbox-cloud anbox-stream-agent location=publicipaddress
/snap/bin/juju config -m appliance:admin/anbox-cloud anbox-stream-gateway location=publicipaddress

amc node set public-address publicipaddress

Then Streaming api join is failing continuously with 400 Bad request

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.